# How to add padding between Text lines in PDFs created using pdf package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on a project which has to create a pdf. In some places there should be spaces between lines. But I can't find a way to do that. I tried adding an empty Text widget between lines to get with spaces in side them. But it didn't took that line as there are only empty spaces. Currently I'm adding a dot in the Text widget to get spaces. Is there any other way to do that?

Link to the pdf package: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

This is the code I use to create the pdf.

```
pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a5,
    margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(32),
    build: (pw.Context context) {
      return <pw.Widget>[
        pw.Text("Methsuwa Family Clinic",
            style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
        pw.Header(
          level: 0,
          child: pw.Text("No: 607, Medamandiya, Panagoda, Homagame.",
              style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
        ),
        pw.Text('Name: ' + name, style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
        pw.Text('Age: ' + age, style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
        pw.Text('Gender: ' + mOF, style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
        pw.Text('.', style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 8)),
        pw.Text('Complains: ' + complain,
            style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
        pw.Text('.', style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 8)),// Trying to create a space between lines
        pw.Text('Blood Pressure: ' + fullPressure,
            style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
        pw.Text('.', style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 8)),
        pw.Table.fromTextArray(
            context: context,
            headerStyle: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
            cellStyle: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
            data: <List<String>>[
              <String>['Drug', 'Amount', 'Days', 'When'],
              ..._data.map((msg) =>
                  [msg["drug"], msg["amount"], msg["days"], msg["when"]])
            ]),
        pw.Text('.', style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 8)),
        pw.Table.fromTextArray(
            context: context,
            headerStyle: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
            cellStyle: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
            data: <List<String>>[
              <String>['Investigations'],
              ...selectedInvestigations.map((msg) => [msg["investigation"]])
            ]),
      ];
    }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [issue](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/129) on the repo about adding space between 2 paragraphs.

The author suggests using:

```dart
SizedBox(height: 20),
// or 
Paragraph(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
  text: 'abcd'
),
```

Does that help?